# Can I use :noindex: in Python docstring with Sphinx autodoc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am trying to build documentation with sphinx, and cannot figure out how to use `:noindex:`.

### Setup

I'm using following extensions:

```py
extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.napoleon",
    "sphinx.ext.todo",
    "sphinx.ext.viewcode",
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx_rtd_theme",
    "m2r2",
]
```

My `.rst` file contains this routine from autodoc to generate documentation:

```
.. automodule:: squid.models.main_model
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

This points to `main_model.py` file, which contains:

```py
class MainModel:
    ... some functions ...

    def to(self, device):
        """
        :noindex:

        Copy of `nn.Module` `to` function but adjusts for stuff.
        """
```

The `:noindex:` above doesn't work. It just shows up in generated documentation as normal text.

### Attempts

I have tried these three ways of putting index:

```py
# Attempt 1
def to(self, device):
    """
    :noindex:

    Copy of `nn.Module` `to` function but adjusts for stuff.
    """

# Attempt 2
def to(self, device):
    """
    .. py:function:: to
      :noindex:

      Copy of `nn.Module` `to` function but adjusts for stuff.
    """

# Attempt 3
def to(self, device):  # :noindex:
    """Copy of `nn.Module` `to` function but adjusts for stuff.
    """
```

But neither worked.

Am I missing something obvious, or is `:noindex:` not supposed to be used outside of `.rst` files? If that's the case then is there any way I can still leverage autodoc, in this case without explicitly defining `MainModel` and `to` functions in `.rst`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:no-index:` is an **option** used under Sphinx and autodoc **directives**.

From Sphinx domains and directives:

> [Basic Markup](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#basic-markup)
>
> If you want to typeset an object description, without even making it available for cross-referencing, you can give the directive option flag `:noindex:` (which implies `:noindexentry:`)

From the autodoc extension:

> [Options and advanced usage - Directives](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directives)
>
> All autodoc directives support the `noindex` flag option that has the same effect as for standard py:function etc. directives: no index entries are generated for the documented object (and all autodocumented members)

What this means is that when you declare a `.. directive::` with the usual syntax, the `:noindex:` option goes underneath the directive (mind the indentation):

```
.. directive::
   :noindex:
```

Declaring a directive inside a docstring is invariably a mistake. What you put inside a docstring are always [docstrings sections](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#docstring-sections). Notice there are [several styles to writing docstrings](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#overview) (Numpy style, Google style, normal reST) but none of them take directives in the docstrings. You write the directives in the `.rst` files.

So in your case you'd write the `.rst` like this:

```
.. automodule:: squid.models.main_model
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
   :noindex:
```

You could also try

```py
.. automethod:: squid.models.main_model.to
   :noindex:
```

and the docstring would like this:

```py
def to(self, device):
    """
    Copy of `nn.Module` `to` function but adjusts for stuff.

    :param device:
    :type device: str
    """
```

or using Google style docstrings

```py
def to(self, device):
    """
    Copy of `nn.Module` `to` function but adjusts for stuff.

    Args:
        device (str): The path of the file to wrap
    """
```